# SSH clients (putty/ZOC/xterm) no longer using tab completion not recognizing arrow keys?

Tags: ssh, terminal, putty

All of a sudden, SSH clients to my web server don't recognize tab for file name completion, and rather insert a physical tab. Also, the arrow keys throw up garbage characters in terminals, rather than moving the cursor.

Ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The shell has probably changed, try tu run bash, tcsh or any other shell you used to use and try tab again.
To see the shell that is configured for your user run [chsh](http://linux.die.net/man/1/chsh). With this command you will also be able to change the shell to bash, tcsh, something else.